# Twitter jQuery typeahead - How to remove the cache

Tags: jquery, caching, twitter-typeahead

I made a query like this... and first time, it ran the filter... cool, and it worked...

But now there are more entries, and it seems to be running off of cache. How do I force it to stop using the cache?

```
var countries = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name); },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 10,
    prefetch: {
        url: Url + '/Country/JsonList',
        filter: function (list) {
            return $.map(list, function (country) { return { name: country.Name }; });
        }
    }
});

countries.initialize();

$('.countries.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    displayKey: 'name',
    source: countries.ttAdapter()
});
```

Comment: oddly clearing the Google Chrome cache and restarting Chrome doesn't seem to clear the prefetch cache either

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the `ttl` property to the filter... and set it to 1 not 0.

```
var countries = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name); },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 10,
    prefetch: {
        ttl: 1,
        url: Url + '/Country/JsonList',
        filter: function (list) {
            return $.map(list, function (country) { return { name: country.Name }; });
        }
    }
});

countries.initialize();

$('.countries.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    displayKey: 'name',
    source: countries.ttAdapter()
});
```

https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md

Comment: Can you please elaborate why "not 0"? I'm looking at prefetching large data sets (happy to do it on every page load) and would like to disable caching completely to avoid hitting local storage limitations which might crash the script.

Comment: Not sure why they said "1 not 0". The ttl is just a number that is added to `now()` milliseconds. The result is then compared to the `now()` at read-time to check for expiry. 0 works. Source: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/f835e162ec4551479114fd245c907ae032de692a/src/bloodhound/persistent_storage.js

Comment: It might work now, perhaps this is relevant to older versions of blood hound, perhaps was a bug. who knows!

Comment: "0" is for not to cache.

Answer (score 23):

I think this is better than the accepted answer:

```
var countries = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name); },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 10,
    prefetch: {
        url: Url + '/Country/JsonList',
        filter: function (list) {
            return $.map(list, function (country) { return { name: country.Name }; });
        },
        cache: false //NEW!
    }
});

countries.initialize();

$('.countries.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    displayKey: 'name',
    source: countries.ttAdapter() //NOTE: .ttAdapter() is deprecated and will be removed in V1
});
```

Comment: Doh, almost lost my mind before figured out it caches the result.